# How to few remove columns and rename columns in CSV using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, csv, parsing

I am new to NodeJS, working on CSV files, where I need to remove a few columns and rename few columns, I have tried following code but as the columns name has space and special characters it's not working, can anyone help me in this?

```
const fs = require('fs')
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const CUserData = [];

fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/UsersData.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', function (row) {
       
    const MemberData = {
        firstname: row.'Member Name (first)',
        lastname: row.'Member Name (last)',
        Email: row.Email

    }
    CUserData.push(MemberData)
  })
  .on('end', function () {
      console.table(CUserData)

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For spaces / special characters you need to use the bracket notation:

```
firstname: row['Member Name (first)']
```